Burning smell coming from LED
This question is related to this original question:
What kind of bulb is this and are there LED equivalents?
I replaced the bulbs in the ceiling fixture with these:
https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07R1X69FP/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_image?ie=UTF8&psc=1#customerReviews
Everything was going fine for quite a while, then one day one of the lights began to flicker. A few days later I noticed a burning smell, and it's coming from the light bulbs (smells like burning plastic). Took the bulbs out and have left that light off.
Attaching a picture of the ceiling fixture that I'm noticing the issue with, it has two lights.

I've replaced the lights in at least 4 other lights in our upstairs with this same product, and haven't noticed any issues with those lights. As soon as I put the problematic bulbs back in and try them out again I notice the smell once more.
Is this just a faulty product? Seems odd that both bulbs are smelling like burning if it was. Any tips on how to safely diagnose / remediate the issue would be greatly appreciated. Thanks all

You can answer this with the reviews of this item where you bought it:

Poor Quality - Don't Last
First bulb only lasted a week. The second for about 3 months, but dimmed quite a bit over that time.


Burned out quickly
I purchased 6 of these bulbs in Feb 2020 for a master bathroom. I doubt they are on an hour a day. By April 2022 one of the bulbs had burned out. I ordered another pair of the bulbs and installed one to replace the burned out bulb. Within a couple of months half the LEDs on the new bulb are not working and two rows flicker on and off. While I suppose the listing doesn't have an expected life span for these bulbs, a standard incandescent bulb advertises 1500 hours and I got far less than 800 hours with the burnt out one and practically nothing from the flickering bulb. LEDs should last 10x longer than incandescent bulbs. Sad for a $10 light bulb. I'm a fan of LED lighting, but stay away from this product.

As DIY.SE is not a review/product recommendation site, the general advice I'd give someone with this issue is Do more research before a purchase, and stick to UL-listed electronics (or whatever certifying body exists in your country/region).

Thanks for the response Fredric. Yeah I saw those reviews as well, most of the products I've found had mixed reviews so I thought that might just be standard. I didn't read any reviews about burning smell though. The lights still work, it just smells like they are going to catch on fire if left on. That seems like a separate issue than the lights just burning out.

@klayman - LEDs have electronics to convert mains voltage to low voltage dc to drive the LEDs. Poor quality electronics getting hot will both lead to the bulb not working as well as possibly doing something worse involving flames.

Thanks Jon. Going to try out this product: https://www.satco.com/products/S11221 . It's cULus listed, so at least that's some assurance. No reviews I could find on the amazon listing or anywhere else, but hopefully that cert is trustworthy.

As others address the bulb quality, you have the answer on that.
I would like to add that you should take the fixture down and check all the wires and connections to be sure they are properly tight and there is nothing burned.
You said you smelled burning plastic. That is because there was plastic that was  overheated. Better safe than sorry and check everything.
